# Excel formula needed: see if a text in one column appears in a second column

Tags: excel-formula

I need a formula that will search for an exact match to A1 in B1:B3, if it finds a match in will a return "yes" on Col C.  See example

```
     A         B       C
1    abc      bcd      yes
2    dfg      fgh      no
3    adf      abc      no
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter the following in cell `C1`. Then copy down:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$B$3,1,FALSE)),"no","yes")
```